# Is it possible to use empathy 2.32 on gnome 2.30?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, upgrade, empathy

I'm running Ubuntu Lucid which contains the Gnome 2.30. The thing is that, I'm really interested on using empathy 2.32, since it fixes a lot of bugs. However I don't want to upgrade the entire system but I really want the new version of empathy :3. I tried using ppa or other methods but no luck. Any idea?

Comment: have you tried compiling it from source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried to build empathy from Maverick for Lucid, but it's not possible due to unmet build dependencies. The easiest other solution that I can think of is just to install the Maverick package using apt, and making use of [pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) to keep the impact on your system to the minimum. This *will* require you to upgrade GTK+ and some other system components, but it's not so bad and works just fine for me. YMMV though, I'm not responsible if you break your system.

Here's how I just did it.

Open up `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and add Maverick sources at the bottom:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

(or use your preferred mirror). Don't do anything with apt yet. Next we'll open up the apt pinning file `/etc/apt/preferences` and tell apt not to install packages from Maverick (see `man apt_preferences` for more):

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=maverick
Pin-Priority: 1
```

Now run `aptitude update` to get the package indexes from these new sources you just added. Next call `aptitude install empathy/maverick-updates` to instruct aptitude to explicitly pull the package from Maverick instead of Lucid (the default). aptitude will tell you it wants to upgrade to a number of packages from Maverick:

```
Upgrade the following packages:
gconf2 [2.28.1-0ubuntu1 (lucid, now) -> 2.31.91-0ubuntu3.1 (maverick-updates)]
gnome-icon-theme [2.28.0-1ubuntu1 (lucid, now) -> 2.31.0-0ubuntu1 (maverick)]
libdbus-glib-1-2 [0.84-1 (lucid, now) -> 0.88-2 (maverick)]
libdbusmenu-glib1 [0.2.9-0ubuntu3.1 (lucid-updates, now) -> 0.3.16-0ubuntu1 (maverick)]
libgail18 [2.20.1-0ubuntu2 (lucid-updates, now) -> 2.22.0-0ubuntu1 (maverick)]
libglib2.0-0 [2.24.1-0ubuntu1 (lucid-updates, now) -> 2.26.0-0ubuntu1 (maverick)]
libgtk2.0-0 [2.20.1-0ubuntu2 (lucid-updates, now) -> 2.22.0-0ubuntu1 (maverick)]
libgtk2.0-bin [2.20.1-0ubuntu2 (lucid-updates, now) -> 2.22.0-0ubuntu1 (maverick)]
libnotify1 [0.4.5-1ubuntu4 (lucid-updates, now) -> 0.5.0-2ubuntu1 (maverick)]
librsvg2-2 [2.26.3-0ubuntu1 (lucid-updates, now) -> 2.32.0-0ubuntu1 (maverick)]
librsvg2-common [2.26.3-0ubuntu1 (lucid-updates, now) -> 2.32.0-0ubuntu1 (maverick)]
libsqlite3-0 [3.6.22-1 (lucid, now) -> 3.7.2-1 (maverick)]
libtelepathy-glib0 [0.10.1-1ubuntu2 (lucid, now) -> 0.12.0-0ubuntu1 (maverick)]
nautilus-sendto-empathy [2.30.3-0ubuntu1 (lucid-updates, now) -> 2.32.1-0ubuntu1 (maverick-updates)]
```

Agree to this if you don't think it's too bad (like I said, worked for me), and you'll end up with a newer Empathy.

Good luck!

Comment: Your solution may work, but it still makes major changes/updates to key components of the system (libdus, etc) which as Marcos already said, is not acceptable.

Comment: I said that. If a package depends on newer libraries then there is now way around it, you have to upgrade to them.

Comment: I'll try this when I get home. It seems the only viable/possible solution. Even if it's doesn't work your research is valid. Bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

you could go to [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/products/lucid-backports/+filebug) and request that the app be backported to lucid

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the package's [page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/empathy) you can find the download links for the latest version (AMD64 or x86):

http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/amd64/empathy/download

http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/i386/empathy/download

The only other dependency you might have to meet is that of the `empathy-common` package.
Besides that, all other packages seems to need gnome versions >= 2.30.2, so you could give it a try.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/all/empathy-common/download

Comment: Unfortunately I get in a depedency hell, since libdbus* and other also need to be changed and they eventually touch key components of the system.

Comment: I couldn't verify that as i'm already using maverick.
I guess it's not that easy then... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method mentioned by [Iain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17327/is-it-possible-to-use-empathy-2-32-on-gnome-2-30/18608#18608), but just do it in a [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot).